# the logout screen does not show on my secondary screen

Tags: login, multiple-monitors, display, wayland, logout

Since ubuntu 16.04 I use dual display for my lenovo t400. i set to automatic login. Now I already upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 beta and I want to try wayland display so I need to logout. The problem is my laptop built in monitor is I think is broken. And my secondary monitor does not show the login display, only the plain violet ubuntu screen. After I logout my built in display on Lenovo shows only the logon display in a blink. I want to logon to the seconday diplay in order to check the wayland option

Comment: Im sorry, the login screen does not show on my secondary monitor

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: If you're after support you should use a #ubuntu+1 site as *focal fossa* hasn't been released yet, however if you're QA-testing and are seeking help with bug reporting, you can also use #ubuntu-quality on IRC or telegram; for help with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: I already encounter this login problem since ubuntu 19.04